# How to configure file on Astra Theme WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme-astra

Is there someone know how and where file to configure Astra themes? I mean, I want to remove specific element as shown below
[image: This is the image]

I want to remove  element that link to [websitedemos.net](https://websitedemos.net)

I just try to find where the files but not yet done, and still figuring out.

Maybe someone know where it is, thanks

Remove specific element on Astra Theme WordPress

Comment: Did you checked theme sections or widgets?

Comment: where you deployed wordpress ?

Comment: @HardikSolanki yes I did

Comment: @MohammedChaaraoui you mean the hosting provider or what?

Comment: @MeshachVijaya Please check template documentation for detail.

Comment: @MeshachVijaya yes the hosting provider ?!!

Comment: @HardikSolanki Well, I'll check it and try to find a way out

Comment: @MohammedChaaraoui It is important? And what a relation between hosting and theme?

Comment: If you are testing in local Environment like Xamp server you can find the files in this path : `C:\xampp\htdocs\astra\wp-content\themes\astra\template-parts`